# Dpad navigation not working on tv for the recyclerview which is below Appbarlayout (recycler view not getting focus with dpad)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tv

I have RecyclerView below Appbarlayout, I have toolbar inside appbarlayout and its getting focused. what I want is to use Dpad controls to navigate recyclerview which I am not able to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I tried to set android:focusable="true" with no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
                android:scrollingCache="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: The RecyclerView and its parent RelativeLayout shouldn't be `focusable`. The item views should be focusable/clickable.

Comment: Can you add an answer explaining what the issue was, and what you changed to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of making RecyclerView and its parent RelativeLayout focusable, I made item view RelativeLayout focusable and boom it worked. Thanks to ataulm :)